# awk ignore case with NR

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have the below code.

```
awk -F":" -v bookName="$bookName" -v newTitle="$newTitle" -v lineNum="lineNum" 'NR==lineNum{gsub(bookName, newTitle)}1'
```

This code basically update a book title to a new title. `lineNum` contains a value of the line number that has been set but the code is not shown here.

I want this line of code to ignore case of bookName, but the following code I tried does not work.

```
awk -F":" -v bookName="$bookName" -v newTitle="$newTitle" -v lineNum="$lineNum" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} NR==lineNum{gsub(bookName, newTitle)}1'
```

Why is that so?

Edit based on [John's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024) reply

*Latest Edit:
So basically my code is as below:

```
read -r bookName
read -r authorName

if grep -iqx "$bookName:$authorName" cutText.txt
then
lineNum=`awk -F":" -v bookName="$bookName" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $0 ~ bookName ":" authorName {print NR}' BookDB.txt`

echo $lineNum
else
echo "Failed"
fi
```

cutText.txt contains:

```
Hairy Potter:Rihanna
MARY IS A LITTLE LAMB:Kenny
Sing along:May
```

BookDB.txt contains

```
Hairy Potter:Rihanna:2:5:20
MARY IS A LITTLE LAMB:Kenny:39:2:1
Sing along:May:38:2:48
```

If I were to input "Mary is a little lamb" as `bookName` and "Kenny" as `authorName`, the program is supposed to output `2`. However, `$lineNum` does not produce any output.

Comment: After replacing  `-v lineNum="lineNum"` with `-v lineNum="$lineNum"`, it works fine for me.

Comment: After replacing, awk still does not substitute. For example, if there is the string "MARY IS A LAMB", and I input `bookName` variable as "mary is a lamb", it does not subtitute to the variable `newTitle`

Comment: Works4me.  If it doesn't work for you , show some sample input and output to demonstrate what problem you are having. The general idea is that a question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  So far, this question is neither complete nor verifiable.

Comment: Hey John! I apologise for the vague question. Upon looking closely at my code that is not in the above question, I realised `lineNum` is not printing out NR, resulting in the code I posted in the question not working. The code is shown below: `lineNum=\`awk -v bookName="$bookName" -v authorName="$authorName" ' BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $0 ~ bookName ":" authorName {print NR}' BookDB.txt`\`  When I tried echoing `$lineNum`, nothing is printed out. I suppose this is the root to the problem.

Comment: Hello John, I truly appreciate your help. I have been trying hard to play around with the command in my previous comment post but I still cannot figure out why echoing `lineNum` does not produce any output when I type "mary is a little lamb". The variable `bookName` in BookDB.txt contains value of "MARY IS A LITTLE LAMB". Despite the `BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}` , it still does not ignore case.

Comment: Please show a short except of your input file (a section just long enough to illustrate the problem).  Also, provide any values for bookName, authorName, etc as may be needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello John! I just edited the question as "Latest edit" ! Would you take a look?

Comment: Make sure you're using `gawk`. `IGNORECASE` is a gawk-specific built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IGNORECASE is gawk-specific, you must not be using gawk. Portably:

```
awk ... '
    NR==lineNum {
        if ( match(tolower($0),tolower(bookName)) ) {
            $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) newTitle substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
        print
    }
'
```

but you really need to start over with your whole script as that mix of shell+grep and using awk to get the line number is just the wrong approach. Post a new question for help on how to write your script correctly.